# how to manage VPN connection with customer when using K8s on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, kubernetes

Apps on AWS K8s clusters (set up with Kops, i.e. not using EKS) are typically accessed via an Application Load Balancer, which resolves to a couple of volatile IP addressses.

Yet frequently, when setting up a site2site VPN, customers ask for an encryption domain with a few static IP addresses, not a DNS name. (They also don't allow large CIDRs in the encryption domain, they demand that you give them only a few specific IPs. For this reason we cannot use the AWS method to set up a s2s VPN, we instead have to use a 3rd party VPN solution such as Cohesive VNS3.)

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Wait... Kops create Elastic IPs for your LoadBalancer, doesn't it?
Aren't those supposed to be fixed?

What's your issue? Can't you just setup your VPN using those, as an encryption domain?

Otherwise, you could still deploy a pair of HAproxy instances, using your ELB FQDN as a backend, setting up your VPN using those proxies as an encryption domain.

Not being sure what's that Cohesive stuff is about, you mention encryption domains, I'll assume IPSEC: you could look into OpenSwan, StrongSwan, OpenBSD's Isakmpd or IKEd, ... Or with a GUI: pfSense, OPNSense, RouterOS, Zentyal, ...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't think Kops creates ElasticIPs for the LB. On this cluster (that was setup by another sysadmin who is now gone) there is no EIP associated with our k8s LB. Yes indeed, I too have thought of the HAproxy solution.